# How to map Google Services Leaderboard user id to current user

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I have game in Unity and I am using Google Play Services plugin. I created leaderboard and want to load the contents programmatically to make it look pretty.

I used PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.LoadScores() method, my leaderboard is being loaded, both PlayerScore and Scores objects are filled, but I have a problem with finding in Scores table current user score. The UserId in PlayerScore object is different then UserId in Scores table.
There is only one, mine score so I am sure that it is the same user.
How can I find my score in Scores table?

```
            PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.LoadScores(
                type,
                start,
                count,
                LeaderboardCollection.Public,
                timespan,
                data =>
                {
                    Debug.Log("GOOGLE USERID " + PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.GetUserId()); // GOOGLE USERID 116254439162396242728
                    Debug.Log("GOOGLELOCAL USERID " + PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.localUser.id); // GOOGLELOCAL USERID 116254439162396242728

                    Debug.Log("PLAYERSCORE USERID " + data.PlayerScore.userID); // PLAYERSCORE USERID 116254439162396242728

                    foreach (var score in data.Scores)
                    {
                            Debug.Log("SCORE USERID " + score.userID); // SCORE USERID a_2248181595467244665
                    }
                });
```